# Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'reference': This element is not expected

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I am getting below error when I go custom simple products details page.
It is working when go to simple product detail page. I am using magento porto theme and recently migrated from magento 1.9 to magento 2.3.3

main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_40b0d6346f25da66374a88a3ad4a3a7b9_page_layout_merged and handles default, catalog_product_view, catalog_product_view_id_1053, catalog_product_view_sku_JLVMC11611-GS, catalog_product_view_type_simple: Please correct the XML data and try again. Element 'reference': This element is not expected.

-->

Comment: Open product in admin you are trying to open on fronted and go to Design section and check is there and xml written in `Layout Update XML` if yes then provide that xml code

Comment: Also you should provide xml code of `vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

Comment: have you checked the XSD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally this issue appeared for migration in magento 1 to magento 2

However here is the fix there is 2 way one is very long you you to open each product and remove xml from `Layout Update XML` and save it.

Note: If you have multi store then you must need to check data for each store to so that you will not get this issue.

There is another very easy way to delete directly from database.

Step 1: Get attbute_id of a 'custom_layout_update' attribute for catalog entity

`SELECT * FROM eav_attribute where attribute_code='custom_layout_update' and entity_type_id=4`

Note: entity_type_id=4 here 4 is catalog entity you must be sure that you are selecting correct entity. If you are not sure then you must run to check catalog entity by below mentioned query:

`SELECT * FROM eav_entity_type where entity_type_code='catalog_product'`

Step 2: Checking attribute value that to verify we are deleting proper data.

`SELECT * FROM catalog_product_entity_text where attribute_id=106 and value IS NOT NULL`

Note: Here attribute_id=106 you will get that id from step 1.

Step 3: Removing all custom_layout_update attribute data.

`DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_text where attribute_id=106 and value IS NOT NULL`

After running this query clear cache from admin and product page will start working.

Note: Make sure you have db backup.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks. It is working now.

Comment: Working for me..

Comment: Worked for me as well, this can work for category too if some one got issue in category page instead of product page, but you will need to change a bit, `entity_type_id=3` instead of `entity_type_id=4` (because it's category entity). And `catalog_category_entity_text` instead of `catalog_product_entity_text`.

Comment: Oh, and it can work for cms page too, search for table `cms_page` and do nearly the same as above.