# M2.4 alternative to reference in design layout

Tags: layout

I just upgraded from M2.3.5 to M2.4.4 and on some product pages I am getting the following error in developer mode:

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'reference': This element is not expected.

This error was not happening with M2.3.5 or M2.3.7p3.

After spending hours searching the net, and disabling all my custom xml files it turns out it was being caused by Design Layout Updates I was using since M1.7.

What is the correct way to add cms blocks after the add to cart button but before the product description button on  a product description page using design layout updates in M2.4.4?

Below is a sample code that is causing the issue.

block_name

Answer (score 0):

Generally this issue appeared for migration in magento 1 to magento 2 and upgraded issue. So can you try below link.

**https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/302505/85907**

Here this link explain very cool. let me know if any query about this.

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't answer the question. I am already aware there are entries in the database that carried over from M1. I could easily delete them myself in mysql, however the question asks how to translate the old <reference commands in design layout update to M2.4.4